# How to connect to a pervasive database with Yii2?

Tags: yii2, odbc, pervasive

I would like to make a connection to a pervasive database in Yii2. I have tried odbc, as it's installed but when I'm trying to create models with Gii I'm getting the error: Connection does not support reading schema information for 'pervasive odbc interface' DBMS.

Could you please point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable odbc and pdo_odbc in PHP (WAMP). This is my db.php:

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'driverName' => 'Pervasive ODBC Interface',
    'dsn' => 'odbc:Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerName=localhost;ServerDSN=MYDB',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
];
```

my controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    try {
        Yii::$app->db->open();
        echo "Connection successful!";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

so it's basically working, but unfortunately not supported by Gii.